# Api of sever which does not have documentation

Tags: api

Assume I have a server example.com. And it is a service with exposed api. But I do not have a documentation, is there way to see the api paths?

Paths like example.com/users,
example.com/events, 
etc

Answer (score 0):

There is supposed to be documentation, since the api is the work of someone, and it will be difficult to know what that person is thinking, or how he has structured his api. You should request the documentation if you can or get an alternative api that can do the same thing but is well documented

Comment: yes, but I cannot request the documentation. It could be internal service without one.

Comment: probably there is some technical way to see available api paths

Comment: if there is no documentation, perhaps they were not expecting an external user to access the api. I am not sure if there is a technical way,